# Ad-Hoc distribution prompt message says (null) would like to install {app name}

Tags: iphone, ios

I've successfully created an ad-hoc file for over-the-air installation of my app for beta testers.  Everything is working as expected apart from the initial message that gets display.

When I click the install link the iPhone prompts the user with the following message:

"(null) would like to install {My App Name}"

Does anyone know how I can replace the (null) text? is there an additional setting in the .plist file I can add?

For the add-hoc distribution I have 4 files - large+small icons, app.ipa and app.plist  -  the .plist file conatins the urls for the icons and app and also contains the a title and subtitle field in the metadata portion.  These 2 both have values in them.

Comment: Did you solved your problem ? I'm searching the same...

Comment: I've updated the question with the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solutions to this.

If the link is sent in an email the "(null) would like to install" will appear when clicking the link.

If however I browse to a webpage which includes the link the message will replace the (null) with the domain name where the webpage is hosted.

So to solve my problem I just email out a link to a webpage which includes the original link.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  If you ask me it looks like an iOS bug.

Comment: I'm working with this and it doesn't look like an iOS bug. The other user posted that the url link is http:/. For some reason, Outlook is changing http:// to http:/.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing similar problem, solved it in following ways-

Issue arise because we use single slace after `http:/` in web page where give **.plist path**.

i.e.

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http:/pathToYourServer/folder/applicationName.plist"> here </a>
```

Now changed, it become-:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://pathToYourServer/folder/applicationName.plist"> here </a>
```

You can also refer this-

[Enterprise distribution prompt message says (null) would like to install {app name}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253914/enterprise-distribution-prompt-message-says-null-would-like-to-install-app-na/14260653#14260653)